# How to accept 2 types of input in c from stdin

Tags: c, while-loop, user-input

Is there a way to accept both these types of input?

One is a letter: v
One is a letter and number: o 20171212

I have something like this:

```
FILE *f = NULL;
int c;
int d;
int pocet = 0;
int* po  = &pocet;
char** spz = NULL;
long b;
while ((c = getchar()) != 'k') {
    getchar();
    switch (c) {
        case 'v': {
            vypis(&f);
            break;
        }
        case 'o': {
            scanf_s("%ld", &b);
            oopis(f,b);
            break;
        }
        case 'n': {
            spz = nope(f, po, spz);
            break;
        }
        case 's': {
            subs(spz, *po);
            break;
        }
        case 'p': {
            prepare(spz, *po);
            break;
        }
        case 'z': {
            zabi(spz, *po);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            printf_s("Skus znova\n");
            break; 
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

The problem with this code is when I enter o 20171212 it doesnt work. Also the goal is to wait until letter '`k`' is pressed and then enter after which the program quits, that's why I am using while cycle and `getchar();`

Comment: If your input is line-based you are better off using `fgets()` and `sscanf`

Comment: My input is from stdin, not from file

Comment: It's all a file, its handle is called: `stdin`

Comment: Why do you drop every second char with `getchar();`? If you would get a string and handl this char by char you should be on the right path.

Comment: @harper he probably tries to get rid of the newline

Comment: fgets was a way to go in this project, thank you